# ../../libtool: line 6000: cd: -l: invalid option; where to solve it?

Tags: linux

I am facing issues with a **make** command. I am compiling Scilab on RHEL for ppc64. The **./configure** went well, now when I did **make all**, I have an issue when compiling the module **umfpack**. I can reproduce this error by entering the modules/umfpack folder, and by typing there **make all**. This is the output:

```
    enter[root@rhel70-misurio umfpack]# /bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -fno-stack-protector -g -O2  -version-number 5:5:1 -Wl,--no-as-needed -o libsciumfpack.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/scilab sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-gw_umfpack.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_res_with_prec.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_taucs_chdel.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_taucs_chfact.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_taucs_chget.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_taucs_chinfo.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_taucs_chsolve.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_umf_ludel.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_umf_lufact.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_umf_luget.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_umf_luinfo.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_umf_lusolve.lo sci_gateway/c/libsciumfpack_la-sci_umfpack.lo libsciumfpack-algo.la -L-lumfpack -lsuitesparseconfig -lumfpack  -lpthread -ldl -lcurses  -lm
../../libtool: line 6000: cd: -l: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `-lumfpack'
```

So it is apparent that somewhere the code is doing "cd -"something. But where...? this is folder where I am.

```
[root@rhel70-hostname umfpack]# ls
etc       libsciumfpack-algo.la  make_all_log  sci_gateway        umfpack.iss
examples  license.txt            Makefile      src                UMFPACK_license.txt
help      locales                Makefile.am   TAUCS_license.txt
includes  macros                 Makefile.in   tests
```

Which are the candidates, in your opinion, where I have to investigate where the mistake is? What would you do in my place to debug?

Thanks!

Comment: So what does line 6000 of libtool look like?

Comment: Check for spaces or leading hyphens in the full path of your working directory. Also, building as root is often not a great idea; since a makefile executes arbitrary commands, running one as root increases the damage that a buggy or malicious makefile can do.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your suggestions! I went into the libtool file and indeed I found that at line 6'000 there was this line of code:

```
   absdir=`cd "$dir" && pwd`
      test -z "$absdir" && \
        func_fatal_error "cannot determine absolute directory name of \`$dir'"
```

And I realised that it was doing "cd -lumfpack" in the script. That was an input I had given to the ./configure script, in which I had to explicitly provide the libumfpack and libsuitesparseparseconfig as an option, since it was using other libraries by default. In that option, I had given:

```
--with-umfpack-library="-lumfpack -lsuitesparseconfig"
```

so then make was doing "cd -lumfpack". So I thought about providing the absolute path of both libraries! So I gave as input:

```
--with-umfpack-library="/usr/local/lib/libumfpack.a /usr/local/lib/libsuitesparseconfig.a"
```

And it successfully ran the configure script and the make.

Another "solution" would have been to remove the umfpack libraries altogether with the option to the configure script:

```
--without-umfpack
```

Hope it helps future programmers compiling Scilab!

Honestly, I think another way could have been feasible, that is specifiying the libumfpack and libsuitesparseconfig libraries in the configure script directly, but I didn't have time then to investigate this. If I will do, I will update this post.